# How to find sum of product of min value and length of sub list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of `n` numbers. I want to divide the list into sub lists, such as the sub list consists of continuous increasing numbers or continuous decreasing numbers. Then take the product of each sub list's min value and it's length. Finally take the sum of all this product's

Input:

```
l = [1,2,6,4,2,3,1,8,9,7]
```

Output:

```
32
```

Details:

```
[1,2,6],[6,4,2],[2,3],[3,1],[1,8,9],[9,7]
(1*3)  +(2*3)  + (2*2)+(1*2)+(1*3)+ (7*2) = 32
```

Code so far:

```
n = 10
l = [1,2,6,4,2,3,1,8,9,7]

tot = 0
count = 0
inc=dec=False
min_val = 1001 # max value in list won't exceed 1000
for idx, e in enumerate(l):
    if idx+1<=n:
        if e > l[idx+1]:
            count+=1
            if min_val > l[idx+1]:
                min_val=l[idx+1]
            inc=True
            dec=False
        elif e < l[idx+1]:
            count+=1
            if min_val > e:
                min_val=e
            dec=True
            # if not inc
            inc=False
```

***Note:** No Two adjacent value will be equal in the list.

**Update-1:**

```
itemp = [1001]
dtemp = [1001]
result=0
for e in l:
    # if not itemp or not dtemp:
    #     itemp.append(e)
    #     dtemp.append(e)
    if e > itemp[-1]:
        if not dtemp:
            itemp.append(e)
        else:
            result+=(min(dtemp)*(len(dtemp)-1))
            dtemp=[1001]
            itemp.append(e)
    elif e < dtemp[-1]:
        dtemp.append(e)
        if not itemp:
            dtemp.append(e)
        else:
            result+=(min(itemp)*(len(itemp)-1))
            itemp=[1001]
            dtemp.append(e)

print(result)
```

This results `0` as output. Can some one help?

Comment: @0x5453 if the numbers in the sequence are: `n==n+1`  or `n > n+1`

Comment: What is the variable `wl`? I see no mention of it anywhere

Comment: @AndiDomi `wl` is typo error. It is list of elements. I update the code. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [1,2,6,4,2,3,1,8,9,7]
local_max= [i for i in range(1, len(l)-1) if l[i-1]<l[i]>l[i+1]]
local_min= [i for i in range(1, len(l)-1) if l[i-1]>l[i]<l[i+1]]
idx= sorted(local_max+local_min +[0,len(l)-1])
idx_pairs = zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:])
sum(min(l[i_1],l[i_2])*(i_2+1-i_1) for i_1,i_2 in idx_pairs)
```

Comment: Can you please explain your approach/algorithm?

Comment: First I find all the indexes for the sublists the start and end plus all local minimas and maximas. Then I order the indeexes and get the sublists as index pairs and for each index pair I calculate the contribution to the result and sum these.

Answer (score 1):

You could identify the breaking positions (peaks and bottoms) using zip to detect changes of increasing/decreasing values between each sequence of 3 elements.  Then use these breaks to form the sub-lists and apply the calculation in a comprehension.

```
L = [1,2,6,4,2,3,1,8,9,7]

breaks = [i+1 for i,(a,b,c) in enumerate(zip(L,L[1:],L[2:])) if (a<b)==(b>c)]
subL   = [ L[s:e+1] for s,e in zip([0]+breaks,breaks+[len(L)]) ]
result = sum(min(s)*len(s) for s in subL)

print(breaks) # [2, 4, 5, 6, 8]  indices of peaks and bottoms
              #                  [1,2,6,4,2,3,1,8,9,7]
              #                       ^   ^ ^ ^   ^
              #                   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
 
print(subL)   # [ [1, 2, 6], [6, 4, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [1, 8, 9], [9, 7]]
              #   0..2+1     2..4+1     4..5+1  5..6+1  6..8+1     8..len(L)
              #   |  |       |  |       |  |    |  |    |  |       |  |
              #  [0] |   +  [2, |       4, |    5, |    6, |       8] |      
              #     [2,         4,         5,      6,      8]      + [len(L)]

print(result) # 32
```

Comment: I don't understand why only 3 elements are chosen. Can you please explain?

Comment: In order to detect a peek or a bottom, the progression needs to invert itself over 3 elements. All other cases are continuation of the same progression (increasing or decreasing). In other words, peaks are Lower-Higher-Lower and bottoms are Higher-Lower-Higher. You only need 3 elements to detect that. There are 6 permutations : 1-3-2 or 2-3-1 is a peak, 3-1-2 or 2-1-3 is a bottom, 1-2-3 is an increasing slope, 3-2-1 is a decreasing slope

Answer (score 0):

```
tot = start = m = n = 0
direc = -1
for n, x in enumerate(lis):
    if n == 0:
        m = x
    else:
        old = lis[n - 1]
        if (x > old and direc == 0) or (x < old and direc == 1):
            tot += m * (n - start)
            start = n - 1
            m = min(old, x)
            direc ^= 1
        else:
            direc = 1 if x > old else 0
            m = min(m, x)
ln = n - start + 1
if ln > 1:
    tot += m * ln
```

Comment: Can you please explain your algorithm/approach?

Comment: It's a simple loop which remeber the previous value in old and the min value in m, when the direction changes from increase to decrease, calc the value to add to tot.